# How to convert enum to POJO using mapstruct?

Tags: java, enums, mapstruct

How can I convert enum to POJO using mapstruct and without custom implementation?

e.g.

```
enum Type {
  T1, T2;

  private String description;

  private Type(String description) {
      this.description = description;
  }

  public String getDescription() { return this.description; }
}
```

to POJO like

```
class TypeDto {
   private Type code;
   private String description;
}
```

FYI,
I use MapStruct 1.1.0.Final.

Comment: Why do you have a `Type` field on your DTO? Aren't you trying to eliminate that object?

Comment: I can use String instead of Type, but I don't think it's a big deal.

Answer (score 3):

I use this for now

```
default TypeDto typeToTypeDto(Type type) {
    return new TypeDto(type.name(), type.getName());
}
```

due to lack of another solution.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly convert from an enum to an object.

You would need to create a `TypeMapper` and an implementation to handle the conversion.

### TypeConversion

```
public class TypeConversion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TypeDto t1 = TypeMapper.INSTANCE.typeToTypeDto(Type.T1);
        TypeDto t2 = TypeMapper.INSTANCE.typeToTypeDto(Type.T2);

        System.out.println(t1);
        System.out.println(t2);
    }
}
```

### Type

```
public enum Type {
    T1("T-One"),
    T2("T-Two");

    private final String description;

    private Type(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }
}
```

### TypeDto

```
public class TypeDto {
    private String description;

    public TypeDto() {
        this("");
    }

    public TypeDto(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("TypeDto { \"description\": \"%s\" }", description);
    }
}
```

### TypeMapper

```
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

@Mapper
public interface TypeMapper {
    TypeMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(TypeMapper.class);

    @Mapping(source = "description", target = "description")
    TypeDto typeToTypeDto(Type type);
 }
```

### TypeMapperImpl

```
public class TypeMapperImpl implements TypeMapper {
    @Override
    public TypeDto typeToTypeDto(Type type) {
        if (type == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return new TypeDto(type.getDescription());
    }
}
```

---

You can make this mapper reusable by creating a generic mapper.

### EnumMapper

```
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;

@Mapper
public interface EnumMapper<T, U extends Enum<?>> {
    @Mapping(target = "description")
    T enumToObject(U type);
 }
```

### EnumMapperImpl

```
public abstract class EnumMapperImpl<T, U extends Enum<?>> implements EnumMapper<T, U> {
    @Override
    public T enumToObject(U type) {
        if (type == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return convert(type);
    }

    protected abstract T convert(U type);
}
```

Then you can use this in your TypeMapper.

### TypeMapper

```
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

@Mapper
public interface TypeMapper extends EnumMapper<TypeDto, Type> {
    TypeMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(TypeMapper.class);
}
```

### TypeMapperImpl

```
public class TypeMapperImpl extends EnumMapperImpl<TypeDto, Type> implements TypeMapper {
    @Override
    protected TypeDto convert(Type type) {
        return new TypeDto(type.getDescription());
    }   
}
```

Comment: Are all *Impl created automatically by mapstruct?

Comment: I believe so. I think it will find whatever implements it on the classpath.

Comment: I don't think TypeMapper will work for 1.1.0.Final mapstruct. I will check.

Comment: @AndreyBeletsky I tested this with the latest version. I did not try an earlier version.

Comment: @AndreyBeletsky Checkout the following project and try building it. The unit test should succeed. [***GitHub: MappingExample***](https://github.com/ryankane/MappingExample).

Comment: Your variant works. I didn't notice you didn't add Type as a field to TypeDTO. It's a common issue here. When you add it you have to add custom implementation or use something like `expression=java(source.name())`.

Comment: Actually, your variant DOES NOT work. You have your implementation of the mapper, not generated one. When I try to generate it I encounter an error `Can't generate mapping method from enum type to non-enum type `.

Answer (score 1):

It's not something that MapStruct can automatically handle for you. Just implement the mapping by hand. MapStruct does not aim to handle every mapping case for you, but automate the common 80% and let you deal with the more exotic cases yourself.